# Importing github project to android studio 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-studio-2.3

I am having a problem on how can I import an android project on Github in Android studio successfully?

I want to run "NavigationDrawer-MaterialDesign" in Android Studio 2.3.3. How do I do that?

Here is the github project Link : Click [here](https://github.com/rudsonlive/NavigationDrawer-MaterialDesign)!

Comment: Please try to be more clear! what is your problem, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi, do you have any link or source where material drawer can be imported and test on Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

I just copy the whole folder into my android studio project folder, and then from there you can open that project from android studio.

Folder should be at some path like:

C:\Users\Your_user_name_goes_here\AndroidStudioProjects

and then on the android side just: on the view, select file => open... and find the path to the folder where you just saved your project.

Comment: Problem is I can't test it and run. I am seeing on Android Studio NavigationDrawer and Gradle Scripts after I open the project

Comment: Try this, on the menu, go to: build => Rebuild project

Comment: That doesn't make any changes to the project or structure

Answer (score 0):

That's not an Android Studio project, but a library actually, so I suggest you to follow the instructions on README (Using gradle to import).

There's a `demo` folder that's actually an Android Studio project, so you can clone (`git clone git@github.com:rudsonlive/NavigationDrawer-MaterialDesign.git`) and on your Android Studio open the demo folder (File -> Open).

Comment: I already open the project and imported where I am seeing NavigationDrawer and Gradle Scripts on Android Studio. The problem is I cannot run it

Comment: Which project are you trying to import? Cause the main project isn't a Android Studio project as well, but a library instead, so you cannot import him, unless you already have an application, then you can use gradle to import that library to your project.

Comment: Is there any project where I can download and test run like http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/ which download is not available for material drawer with tabs just for a test-run??

Comment: Is there anyway I can run it using that library or project?